# integral of $x^ae^{bx}$ when a and b are fractions

Tags: integration, calculus

I found some questions asking the integral of $\int x^ae^{bx}dx$ but only when $a$ and $b$ are integers. I wonder is there any way to calculate this integral when $a$ and $b$ are fractions?

Comment: If you want the full integral $\int_0^\infty$ then you get results related to gamma functions (and your original expression is related to the density of a gamma distribution)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be rewritten as finding the integral

$$\int_0^y x^ae^{-bx}dx \quad \text{with $a>-1$ and $b>0$}$$

We can relate this to the [incomplete gamma function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) by substituting $bx = t$, $z=a+1$, then this changes into

$$\begin{array}{rcl}\int_0^y x^ae^{-bx}dx &= &\int_0^{by} (t/b)^ae^{-t} \frac{dt}{b} \\&=& \left(\frac{1}{b}\right)^{1+a} \int_0^{by} t^ae^{-t} dt\\& =& \left(\frac{1}{b}\right)^{1+a}  \gamma(a+1,by)\\ & =& \left(\frac{1}{b}\right)^{z}  \gamma(z,by)\end{array}$$

and the problem reduces to estimating $\gamma(z,by)$ by a [power series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Evaluation_formulae).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what if b<0?

Comment: @Joey you can also work with negative values by [analytical continuation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Continuation_to_complex_values) but I am not sure about how to work that out. I imagine that the power series still works but you need to add some factor in front of it according to the formula that defines the analytical continuation.

Comment: Note that I switched the notation from $b$ to $-b$, so if you have a negative $b$ then this corresponds to a positive $b$ in my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation. I’ll have a look at that.

Comment: Oh I see, is that means your derivations are based on the negative exponential of e?

Comment: @Joey yes, I assume that the exponential has a negative coefficient $e^{-bx}$ with $x\geq 0$ and $b>0$. This translates to $e^{bx}$ with $x\geq 0$ and $b<0$.

Comment: Sorry for the bothering but I’m wondering that why the threshold for the integral is y/b? If it refers to the integral of t=bx, why it’s not by?

Comment: @Joey you are right, that was an error.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Btw what you are referring to is the lower incomplete gamma function. Is it still appropriate for the upper incomplete gamma function?

Answer (score 1):

May be written in terms of a confluent hypergeometric function:
$$
\int x^a e^{bx}\;dx = \frac{x^a}{b}\;\big(e^{bx} - {}_1F_1(a,a+1,bx)\big) .
$$
For proof, differentiate a power series series term-by-term
\begin{align}
{}_1F_1(a,a+1,bx) &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a}{(a+k) k!}b^kx^k
\\e^{bx} - {}_1F_1(a,a+1,bx) 
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{k!} - \frac{a}{(a+k) k!}\right)b^kx^k
\\ 
\frac{x^a}{b}\left(e^{bx} - {}_1F_1(a,a+1,bx) \right)
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{k!} - \frac{a}{(a+k) k!}\right)b^{k-1}x^{k+a}
\\ 
\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{x^a}{b}\left(e^{bx} - {}_1F_1(a,a+1,bx) \right)\right]
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\right)b^{k-1}x^{k+a-1}
=x^ae^{bx}
\end{align}